# SQL / Impala , how to more quickly and efficient write increasing conditional statements?

Tags: sql, impala

I hope someone can help me here.

I'm writing a CASE in impala to find the missed lines in the table.

However, I need to write my example below to WHEN 1000 = 999. Instead of writing 1000 CASE lines, is there a more efficient and quicker solution that requires less code? It would help me a lot. Thank you.

```
CASE WHEN dif_tradecount = 2 THEN 1
            WHEN dif_tradecount = 3 THEN 2
            WHEN dif_tradecount = 4 THEN 3
            WHEN dif_tradecount = 5 THEN 4
            WHEN dif_tradecount = 6 THEN 5
            WHEN dif_tradecount = 7 THEN 6
            WHEN dif_tradecount = 8 THEN 7
            WHEN dif_tradecount = 9 THEN 8
            WHEN dif_tradecount = 10 THEN 9
            WHEN dif_tradecount = 11 THEN 10
            WHEN dif_tradecount = 12 THEN 11 .....
            ELSE null
            END AS missed_messages
```

Comment: if (dif_tradecount>1) then dif_tradecount-1 else dif_tradecount ?

Answer (score 2):

if i got your task correct:

```
CASE
    WHEN dif_tradecount > 1 and dif_tradecount<=1000 THEN dif_tradecount-1
    ELSE null
END AS missed_messages
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
(case when dif_tradecount between 2 and 1000
      then dif_tradecount - 1
 end) as missed_messages
```

I wonder why the `case` is necessary.  Perhaps:

```
nullif(dif_tradecount - 1, 0) as missed_messages
```

would also work.